# C++ initialize a unique_ptr with int 0 problem

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, nullptr

environment: C++11/14 and MacOS Clion

First, I know it is better to construct a unique_ptr with `nullptr` rather than with `int: 0`, but I just wonder what causes the following two compilation results:

```cpp
// compile just fine
class MyClass {};

void MyFunc(unique_ptr<MyClass>) {

}

int main() {
    MyFunc(0);
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// compile error
class MyClass {};

void MyFunc(unique_ptr<MyClass>) {

}

int main() {
    MyFunc(int(0));
    return 0;
}
```

the latter one with error:

> note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'unique_ptr' for 1st argument

After examining `unique_ptr`'s constructor, I find the following a canditate:

```cpp
constexpr unique_ptr( nullptr_t ) noexcept;
```

So I try further:

```cpp
// good
int main() {
    nullptr_t mynullptr(0);
    return 0;
}
```

on the other hand:

```cpp
// error
int main() {
    nullptr_t mynullptr(int(0));
    return 0;
}
```

with message:

> error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'std::nullptr_t' (aka 'nullptr_t') with an rvalue of type 'int'
>
> nullptr_t mynullptr(int(0));

So is it because the initialization of `nullptr` that leads to the compile error?

Comment: literal `0` may be converted to nullptr  ; other integer expressions may not (even if they are constant and have value zero)

Comment: @M.M thank you, I believe you're right. Is the convertion between `nullptr` <==> `0` regulated by C++ standard? Because the  `nullptr` is a keyword so I cannot find anything valuable from the IDE's Goto Definition.

Comment: Unique_ptr is default assigned a nullptr as default value.
After make_unique or new assignment then the point is assigned to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit on the comment of M.M:

> literal 0 may be converted to nullptr ; other integer expressions may not (even if they are constant and have value zero)